# Multiply all elements in a generic vector?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to multiply all elements in a vector but I can't figure out how to do this with a reference. Here is an example:

```
struct S<T> {
    elements: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> std::ops::MulAssign<T> for S<T>
where
    T: std::ops::MulAssign,
{
    fn mul_assign(&mut self, val: T) {
        for i in 0..self.elements.len() {
            self.elements[i] *= val;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `val`
  --> src/lib.rs:11:33
   |
9  |     fn mul_assign(&mut self, val: T) {
   |                              --- move occurs because `val` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
10 |         for i in 0..self.elements.len() {
11 |             self.elements[i] *= val;
   |                                 ^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

I've tried this with references in different ways, but I didn't succeed. How do you do this? I would prefer to implement this without the `Copy` trait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
struct S<T> {
    elements: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> std::ops::MulAssign<&T> for S<T>
where
    for<'a> T: std::ops::MulAssign<&'a T>,
{
    fn mul_assign(&mut self, val: &T) {
        for i in self.elements.iter_mut() {
            *i *= val;
        }
    }
}
```

- Uses `iter_mut` to iterate over vector
- Requires that your elements support multiplication by borrowed `T` (which seems to be the case for [`isize` and others](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.MulAssign.html#method.mul_assign-34)

Answer (score -4):

Extra notes:

I wouldn't recommend direct index assignment such as `elements[i]`. You can achieve the same with a `for element in self.elements`. Rust iterators will directly understand you want to iterate over the whole vec, so you can apply the processing on the `element` object.
A direct index access will add bound-checking at runtime, making it a slower solution, instead of safely iterating over the array with the length pre-calculated.

Furthermore, if you want to apply the same processing over the vec, the `.map()` method can help greatly, taking a closure to defiune the processing you want. Rust offers many such functional higher-order-functions, that are much more concise and efficient.

Comment: This won't do anything as the adapter is not consumed. You can immediately see, this can't possibly mutate the Vector. Were you looking for `.iter_mut().for_each(...)`?

Comment: oh yeah, `iter_mut()` should be a better generator. I woiuld rather use `for_each` for things that  affect other variables, `map` is more appropriate for such inner processing. My point was to at least steer away from direct indexing, which is not a very rust-like way of doing things, introduces a slower run time bound checker impacting performance, and is arguably harder to read and understand.

Comment: Friendly pointer: Maybe you should go read a little more on rusts iterators, especially their so-called lazyness. The only way to actually do a thing with an iterator is by driving it, using consumers like `fold`, `count`, `for_each`, etc. The value returned by `.map(...)` is just a struct implementing the `Iterator` trait for this conceptually 'mapped' iterator, it doesn't do a thing by itself.